# Algorithm of intersecting set of infinite Iterators

Tags: c#, algorithm, iterator, infinite-loop

I have to implement a scheduling algorithm similar to an [Outlook Meeting Organizer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S73l6.gif) where I have several persons participating in the meeting and organizer finds the time slot when all persons from invitelist are available. So let's say I have a 3rd party service that implements the following interface:

```
interface IAvailabilityProvider
{
     IEnumerable<DateTimeInterval> GetPersonAvailableTimeSlots(
              string personName, DateTime startFrom);
}
```

Where DateTimeInterval is:

```
class DateTimeInterval{
   public DateTime Start {get;set;}
   public TimeSpan Length {get;set;}
}
```

GetPersonAvailableTimeSlots returns **infinite iterator**, it will enumerate all time slots of person's working hours excluding weekends and holidays and stuff like that, infinite to the future.

My task is to implement a function that takes a set of those iterators and returns another iterator of the intersections:

```
IEnumerable<DateTimeInterval> GetIntersections(
    string[] persons, DateTime startFrom);
```

It gets iterators of available time slots for all persons and returns intersected timeslots, when all those persons available. Internally I have to implement the following function:

```
IEnumerable<DateTimeInterval> GetIntersections(
    IEnumerable<DateTimeInterval>[] personsAvailableSlots);
```

Comment: How big are the time slots in the iterators returned by 3rd party service?

Comment: You appear to have used the class DateTimeRange without derfining it. Are these also supposed to be DateTimeInterval or are they something else?

Comment: Not that I am C# expert but isn't your function `GetIntersections` attempting to perform infinite amount of operations (and also receiving infinite amount of data as input).

Comment: @moreON, thanks. By DateTimeRange I meant DateTimeInterval - forgot to rename it everywhere. Fixed.

Comment: @displayName, timeslots can be of any size. It may be from DateTime.MinValue->TimeSpan.MaxValue as well as 5 minutes slots.

Comment: @PhilippMunin: I saw the Outlook Meeting Organizer after you posted this question. OMO provides details for half hour long slots with times beginning from x'o clock to x:30. If you improve the implementation of `IAvailabilityProvider` then your problem will get easier. Otherwise, it seems very hard.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev, Iterators is cross language concept, it allows you to iterate through loops (while-/for-/...) including infinite loops (while(true) {yield 'blah';} )). Event Javascript since ES6 includes iterators/generators: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#Generators

Comment: @displayName, unfortunately I cannot touch IAvailabilityProvider, this is external service for me.

Comment: @PhilippMunin: Create another iterator around them then and have that iterator give you times in 30 min slots as explained in previous comment. Then use these new iterators to find the intersection.

Comment: @displayName, thanks for your suggestion, I hope to find better solution

Comment: Definetely they are cross language concept, thus i placed my first comment. I think the iterator you are looking for must have all person's iterators as properties. Furthermore, instead of passing iarrays of available times you should have just `Long lastConsideredTimestamp`. I can provide you with pseudocode in, say Java or C++ if you are interested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution seems to be pretty straightforward for me.

```
    static IEnumerable<DateTimeInterval> GetIntersections(IEnumerable<DateTimeInterval>[] personsAvailableSlots)
    {
        var enumerators = personsAvailableSlots.Select(timeline => timeline.GetEnumerator()).ToArray();

        // Intersection is empty when at least one of iterators is empty.
        for (int i = 0; i < personsAvailableSlots.Length; i++) if (!enumerators[i].MoveNext()) yield break;

        while (true)
        {
            // first we ensure that intersection exists at the current state
            // if not so, we have to move some iterators forward
            var start = enumerators.Select(tl => tl.Current).Max(interval => interval.Start);

            foreach (var iter in enumerators)
                while (iter.Current.Start + iter.Current.Length <= start)
                    if (!iter.MoveNext()) yield break;

            // now we check if the interval exists
            var int_start = enumerators.Select(tl => tl.Current).Max(interval => interval.Start);
            var int_end = enumerators.Select(tl => tl.Current).Min(interval => interval.Start + interval.Length);

            if (int_end > int_start)
            {
                //if so, we return it
                yield return new DateTimeInterval()
                {
                    Start = int_start,
                    Length = int_end - int_start
                };

                // and, finally, we ensure next interval to start after the current one ends
                //
                // CAUTION: We are able to move iterators whose current interval have passed only. 
                // We will miss huge spans which cover several intervals in other iterators otherwise.
                //
                // In fact we should move the only inerator - that one wich currently limits the last result
                foreach (var iter in enumerators)
                    while (iter.Current.Start + iter.Current.Length == int_end)
                        if (!iter.MoveNext()) yield break;
            } 
        }
    }
```

I have tested this for several simple scenarios, hope i'm not missing something important.